# Two social apps for one provider in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

Is it possible to have two social apps for one provider?

Here is my use case:
I want to have two social apps for the "Microsoft" provider. One will be for organizations only and the other one will be for consumers (any user with a Microsoft account).

I know that I can set:
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
'microsoft': {
'TENANT': 'organizations',
}
}

to only allow the organization's users to authenticate. And for consumers, I can set it to consumers (which is the default value). But the problem is I am unable to find a proper way to implement this idea. If anyone have any idea how I can implement this? or whether this is possible or not?